# How do I correctly traverse through packets after reading the header and finding out the packetlength?

Tags: c++, ifstream, binary-data

Given this header format:

[image: Header Format]

I am trying to traverse and print the Length and Num Market Updates:

```
std::ifstream fileOpener(m_rawInputFileName, std::ios::binary);
if (!fileOpener.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "Error: could not open file" << std::endl;
    fileOpener.close();
    return;
}

short int packetLength;
short int numOfMarketUpdates;
while (fileOpener.read((char *)&packetLength, 2) &&
        fileOpener.read((char *)&numOfMarketUpdates, 2))
{
    cout << packetLength << ":" << numOfMarketUpdates << endl;
    fileOpener.seekg(-4, std::ios::cur);
    fileOpener.seekg(packetLength, std::ios::cur);
}
```

What am I doing wrong, or is the data inaccurate?

Comment: I assume you tried with only one seek, `fileOpener.seekg(packetLength - 4, std::ios::cur);`?

Comment: Yes, I did! I get stuck in this infinite loop, I'm assuming, it is reading 4 as length and going back to 0 and seeking again by 0...

Comment: Side note: You probably won't run into this, but `short int` [is only guaranteed to be **at least** 16 bits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Standard_integer_types). You almost never see it as anything else, but just to be sure, use a [fixed width integer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), specifically `int16_t`.

Comment: Yup, No luck.......

Comment: One of the best tools for figuring out infinite loops is the debugger. You've done the next best thing by dumping the the length to the console. You've confirmed that it doesn't happen to be 4, yes?

Comment: Add in a few `tellg`s to see where the stream says the offset is to make sure you and the stream are in agreement.

Comment: 12544:512
1024:4611
20545:8268
0:150
0:150
0:150
0:150
0:150
0:150
This is the first 10 outputs I get, I am not sure why but I get stuck with 0:150 for the rest of the execution. also, Num of Market updates must always be < Packet length, so even the second iteration of the loop seems to be flawed.

Comment: Come to think of it, if you get the position of the stream before you start reading and store it `fileOpener.seekg(start_loc +packetLength  , std::ios::beg);` should be more reliable See the [note here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg#Notes).

Comment: Change `cout << packetLength << ":" << numOfMarketUpdates  << endl;` to ``cout << packetLength << ":" << numOfMarketUpdates << ":" << fileOpener.tellg() <<  endl;` and make sure the file position makes sense as you traverse.

Comment: Tactical note: There's no point to closing the file in the body of `if (!fileOpener.is_open())`. You only got there if the file didn't open.

Comment: OK, I looked closer at the outputs you got. `packetLength` of 0 means don't go nowhere. That's obviously the cause. Now you need to figure out why it's zero. Check the file protocol. Maybe a zero packet length is supposed to be used like the null terminator in a string.

Comment: it says that "All data is in network byte order." Does that have anything to do with this? Also 'Null terminator in a string' was my thought as well, when I read the data byte by byte and parse the packet, there are 5 bytes allocated for the symbol data at offset 3, and the next data does not start at 8 but starts at 9. (I got this by a lot of trial and error)

Comment: Network byte order means after reading you should use the function `ntohs` to convert the byte order of each number. `cout << ntohs(packetLength) << ":" << ntohs(numOfMarketUpdates) << endl;` (it is doing a very quick calculation to convert the number to the right format)

Comment: Add the information about the byte order to the question so future askers can easily find it and understand the answers the question gets. And since you want to use the corrected values to compute the next seek location, you probably want to do the `ntohs(packetLength)` ahead of the printing and save the result for the seek. If that corrects the problem, let us know.

Comment: [Some quick reading on byte order and how we got into this mess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: Stackoverflow usage note: Don't edit the Question to include an answer. Write an Answer instead. Rationale: This is a Question and Answer site, not a forum. Every page contains one Question and zero or more Answers. Your answer looks solid, so just copy it in to the answer text box at the bottom of the page and maybe expand a bit on byte order to help out other new programmers who trip over this in the future and can't figure out on their own why `ntohs` solved the problem.  Side note: user253751 beat me to the explanation by a couple minutes, so credit them

Answer (score 0):

Answer: I missed an Important Detail: "All data is in network byte order."
Hence, the correct code was:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

std::ifstream fileOpener(m_rawInputFileName, std::ios::binary);
if (!fileOpener.is_open())
{
    std::cout << "Error: could not open file" << std::endl;
    return;
}

short int packetLength;
short int numOfMarketUpdates;
while (fileOpener.read((char *)&packetLength, 2) &&
        fileOpener.read((char *)&numOfMarketUpdates, 2))
{
    packetLength = nthos(packetLength);
    numOfMarketUpdates = nthos(numOfMarketUpdates);
    cout << packetLength << ":" << numOfMarketUpdates << endl;
    fileOpener.seekg(-4, std::ios::cur);
    fileOpener.seekg(packetLength, std::ios::cur);
}
```

nthos converts network byte order to host byte order. Network Byte order is configured to be in a big-endian which may be different than your host byte order so It would not make sense unless you convert it into your host byte order.

Credits to user253751 for pointing this out.